# Drive in reserve for greater mileage

Tags: motorcycle

I heard from random person stating that reserve wall opening is relatively small compared with normal opening resulting in constriction in fuel flow hence leading to greater mileage. Someone may please validate this statement.

Comment: Don't think so, the increased mileage is probably due to the panic of the rider knowing they have little fuel and slowing down to make sure they get to the next fuel station.

Comment: I don't know what is a "reserve wall opening", but typically modern vehicles don't even have a "reserve" in the sense of having a separate tank or separate pickup. (you might have a reserve on a moped, atv etc with no fuel gage. )

Comment: @agentp He's referring to the carb petlock that we get on motorcycles here in India. Modern vehicles don't have a "reserve" because they are fuel injected.

Answer (score 7):

IMO I don't think so, the increased mileage is probably due to the panic of the rider knowing they have little fuel and slowing down to make sure they get to the next fuel station.
Also, the reserve tap is usually on the tank and fuel mixture is controlled at the carburettor or fuel management system.

Comment: I agree. If the petcock was providing less fuel to the carbs than they were using, the level in the bowl would drop and you'd have fuelling issues. The pickup for reserve is lower in the tank than the main pickup, so you'll get more fuel out of the tank. This will increase your range, but the mileage shouldn't change.